# MySQL Database not updating

Tags: java, mysql

Using java to connect to a mySQL database, if I use a update query like

```
Update <table_name> set SID='143' where SATR='temp';
```

and query.execute() return two, that is two entries with SATR as 'temp', but if I check the database no change !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you turned off auto-commit but forgotten to explicitly call [`commit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit%28%29) by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not getting any exceptions,you may call **commit()** method.

auto-commit option may be off.